# cftool not fitting on custom fit

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm trying to do a fit on cftool for a basic oscillator.  The problem is that Matlab won't make a fit; it keeps drawing a straight line. I've been experimenting with the starting points and limits, but to no avail.

The problem is probably something trivial, but I can't figure out the problem.

Current fit:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using custom equation `y = f(x) = a * exp(-b*x) * sin(dx+e) + c`.

Matlab understands `dx` inside the `sin` above as a constant coefficient, so you have the `sin` of a constant, which is a constant number itself.

`cftool` is left then trying to approximate a sinusoidal motion with `f(x)`, which at this point is a custom exponential function of the type `const * exp(-const * x) + const`, so the best it can do is to yield the mean value, that is, `~0.176`.

In order to correct this, just substitute `d*x` for `dx` inside the `sin` in your custom function.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the pertinent answer from Lingo.

In practical use of non-linear regression sofware, a frequent cause of failure or of not good convergence is the initial setting of values of the parameters. The values of parameters given below would be very good to start a non-linear regression calculus.

[image]

Those values are probably more or less biaised because the data was not available on numerical form but only from the graph provided by the OP. "Substitue" data was obtained from scanning the graph. This isn't an accurate way.

NOTE : The linearised regression method used to compute the above approximate values is explained in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales